# Parsley.js Trigger Error on AJAX

Tags: ajax, validation, parsley.js

I am using parsley.js for client-side validation.
I have a field called username, which must be unique. The field looks like this:

```
<input type="text" name="loginUsername" id="loginUsername" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" data-minlength="2" data-maxlength="40" data-required="true">
```

This is my ajax function:

```
function validateField(field)
{
    var isValid = $( '#'+field ).parsley( 'validate' );
    if (!isValid) return false;
    return true;
}

$( '#regUsername' ).blur(function(){
    if (!validateField('regUsername')) return false;
    var username = $(this).val();
    $.post('<?= SITE_ROOT; ?>/ajax/ajaxUserActions.php',
    {
        data: 'checkUniqueUsername',
        username: username
    }, 'json')
    .done(function(data){            
        if (data.error)
        {                
        }            
    })
    .fail(function(){ $( '#loader' ).hide(); });
});
```

If the is an error I would like to trigger a parsley error and then show a custom message.
Does anyone know how to do this. I am thinking something like this:

```
$('#regUsername').attr('data-error-message', 'Username Taken').trigger('parsley-error');
```

I am not sure, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason why you don't want to use a custom validator? 
I think it is more clear if you define a new custom validator when parsley is applied to your form.

This is how I do it:
In your input add "parsley-username":

```
<input type="text" name="loginUsername" id="loginUsername" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Username" data-required="true" parsley-username >
```

When you bind parsley to your form, you should define a new custom validator named "username", like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( '#form' ).parsley( {
    validators: {
      username: function() {
            return {
                validate: function(val) {
                    var response = false;

                    $.ajax({
                        url: SITE_ROOT +  "ajax/ajaxUserActions.php",
                        data: {'username': val, 'data': 'checkUniqueUsername'},
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'get',
                        async: false,
                        success: function(data) {
                            if (data.total > 0)
                                response = false;
                            else
                                response = true;
                        },
                        error: function() {
                            response = false;
                        }
                    });

                    return response;
                },
                priority: 32
            }
        }
    }
  , messages: {
      username: "Your username is already taken. Please insert other value"
    }
} );
</script>
```

A few things you should be aware:

1. In your example, you define your URL using a PHP constant. In my code, I assume you have a javascrip variable named SITE_ROOT with the same value as the php variable. If you insert this code inside a php file, it will work with your constant (although, I do not recomend using this code inside php. It will be more clear inside a javascript file).
2. The ajax request must have **async** defined to false. This way, the rest of the code must wait for the ajax to be completed.
3. My code assumes that your AJAX will echo a JSON object with a property called "total". It total = 0, the username is not taken.

This code works with parsley 1.*

**Update for Parsley 2.***

As of Parsley 2.0, the input will have the following attributes:

```
<input type="text" name="loginUsername" id="loginUsername" class="form-control"
    placeholder="Username" data-parsley-required data-parsley-username >
```

And you now must bind the validator like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.ParsleyValidator
        .addValidator('username', function (value, requirement) {
             var response = false;

               // Your code to perform the ajax, like before

                return response;
        }, 32)
        .addMessage('en', 'username', 'Your username is already taken.');
</script>
```

Another possibility is to use the built in remote ajax validator ([see the docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#remote))